# Using the \chemfig package to draw inorganic compounds

Tags: chemfig

I'm trying to draw a similar molecule as the picture below using the `\chemfig` package, but don't really know where to start.

How would I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this as a start, but actually, you should probably consult the [documentation of the package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemfig), which explains everything very nicely.

The key is, to identify one connection that serves as the main part of the structure. In your example, it is a bit difficult to decide, but I chose `Cl-Co-Cl`. With parens, you can add branches, like in this example:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\chemfig{Cl-[6]Co(<:[3]H_2O)(<[5]H_2O)(<[7]H_2O)(<:[9]H_2O)-[6]Cl}

\end{document}
```

[image]